# How to calculate Hugin lens data

Tags: metadata, compact-cameras, hugin

I shot a bunch of pictures in order to create a panorama on my computer using [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/).
My camera is a [Sony PowerShot DSC T-100](http://www.sony.co.uk/product/dsc-t-series/dsc-t100/technical-specifications).

When loading images in Hugin, it asks me to provide some "Lens data" (screenshot), but I don't know how to calculate these data from the specs and the EXIF data of my pictures.
**How do I know what to fill into the form fields?**

[image: lens data dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use **6.03** for the *Focal length multiplier* field you should be good to go. The Sony PowerShot DSC T-100 lists the 5.8-29mm focal length as 35 equivalent to 35-175mm. This figures out to 6.035, but the 1/2.5" sensor of your camera is in a 4:3 ratio instead of the standard 35mm 3:2 ratio. The diagonal of a standard 35mm film frame divided by the 7.18mm diagonal of the Sony's sensor yields a value of 6.02.